# with this docker-compose configuration, why is 8080 considered used?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

to set the context, i have a very basic kafka server setup through a docker-compose.yml file, and then i spin up a ui app for kafka.

depending on the config, the ui app will/wont work becuase of port 8080 being used/free.

my question is how does 8080 tie into this, when the difference between working and non working configs is the host ip.

btw this is done in wsl (with the wsl ip being the ip in question `172.20.123.69`.)

ui app:

```
podman run \
    --name kafka_ui \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    -e KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME=local \
    -e KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=172.20.123.69:9092 \
    -d provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
```

ui works with this kafka server config:

```
version: "2"

services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper-server
    image: docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3.8
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - "/home/rndom/volumes/zookeeper:/bitnami/zookeeper"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka-server
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.3
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - "/home/rndom/volumes/kafka:/bitnami/kafka"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://172.20.123.69:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: bridge
  kafka_data:
    driver: bridge

networks:
  downloads_default:
    driver: bridge
```

notice the environment variable `KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` has the wsl ip.

ui doesn't work with the following:

```
version: "2"

services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper-server
    image: docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3.8
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - "/home/rndom/volumes/zookeeper:/bitnami/zookeeper"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka-server
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.3
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - "/home/rndom/volumes/kafka:/bitnami/kafka"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: bridge
  kafka_data:
    driver: bridge

networks:
  downloads_default:
    driver: bridge
```

the latter i got from the official bitnami docker hub repo.

the error i get when i use it:

```
*************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
*************************
etc etc.

Web server failed to start Port 8080 was already in use
```

Since i got it to work, this is really just for my own understanding.

Comment: Do you have locally installed nginx,apache or even other docker container already running on `8080`?

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram i do not.  i ran both docker files in the same exact environment...

Answer (score 0):

try the command "netstat -tupan" and check if 8080 is not used by any other process.

Comment: i tried `alias netstat='/mnt/c/Windows/System32/netstat.exe'
netstat` and did not see anything.  but i did this on the host.  the ui app runs in its own container, and thats where i get the error.  so not sure why what happens in the kafka server is impacting that...

Answer (score 0):

- Do use `KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092`
- Don't use `podman run` for one container. Put the UI container in the same compose file
- Use `KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=kafka:9092`

---

If you still get errors, then as the error says, the port is occupied, so use a different one like `8081:8080`. That has nothing to do with the Kafka setup.

---

This Compose file works fine for me

```
version: "2"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3.8
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.3
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  kafka_ui:
    image: docker.io/provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME=local
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=kafka:9092
```

Comment: tried this exactly... still get the 8080 error.  i put the ui into the compose file, and used `8081:8080`.

i've also tried a variation with the ui in the compose file, where instead of `kafka` i use the wsl ip for example: `KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://172.20.123.69:9092` and `KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=172.20.123.69:9092`  both with `8081:8080` mind you...

Comment: [You don't need to use any IP addresses](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). But that isn't your problem anyway. Your error is coming from the UI container itself, it seems. I suggest you open an issue at https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui/issues

Comment: @rndom In any case, please see Compose file in my answer